# def in foreach Tikz

Tags: foreach

I am a beginner in foreach command !

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1}{%
        \def\n{23} 
        \node at (0, -\i) {\n} ;
        \def\n{24}
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to change the value of a \def in a foreach loop ?

Thanks

@Andrew Stacey

[image]

Here is my final code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\newcommand \DivisionBase[2][2]{ 
%le premier parametre #1 par defaut est donc 2
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \base{#1}
\def \n{#2}
\def \cd{-0.7} %on peut jouer sur l'inclinaison de l'escalier 
\def \quasiNBdigit {\n} 
% C'est le nombre de digit - 1 ; j'ai mis n par defaut
  \node (a0) at (0,0) {$\n$} ;
  % ai = bi*qi + ri
  \global\let\mya= \n
  \global\let\myb = \base
%  \pgfmathsetmacro \quasiNBdigit {int(log2(\n))}
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\quasiNBdigit}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro \myq {int(\mya/\myb)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro \myr {int(\mya - \myb*\myq)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro \j {\i+1}
  \coordinate (a\i) at (\i, \cd*\i) ;
  \node (b\i) at (\j, \cd*\i) {$\myb$} ;
  \node (q\i) at (\j, \cd*\j) {$\myq$} ;
  \pgfmathsetmacro \intensite {10*(\i+1)}
  \node[fill = red!\intensite] (r\i) at (\i,\cd*\j) {$\myr$} ;
  \coordinate (T) at ($ (a\i)!.5!(b\i) $) ;
  \draw[thick] (T) -- ++(0,-1) ;
  \coordinate (M) at ($ (a\i)!.5!(q\i) $) ;
  \draw[thick] (M) -- ++(1,0) ;
  \ifnum \myq<1
      \breakforeach
  \fi
  \global\let\mya=\myq
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\DivisionBase{57}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def` is a low level command and should not be used on a regular basis, unless you exactly know what to do with it. Instead you can use `\newcommand` before your loop and then `\renewcommand` into your `foreach` loop.

Comment: There are other (and better) ways to achieve what you have written, but I suspect it might be a simpler version of what you really want to do.  Can you edit in some details if your actual use-case so that we can advise you well?

Comment: For example `\foreach[evaluate=\i as \n using \i+23]` will work.

Comment: But if you *really* want to use `\def`, you'll need to use `\gdef` (but I don't recommend that as then `\n` is globally defined).

Comment: @Andrew : edit is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary question has been answered in the comments: either use the `\global` key word (or equivalently `\gdef`) or, as Qrrbrbirlbel says, use the `remember` key on the `\foreach` loop. The following code gives an example of how to use the latter (`remember`), but I also took the opportunity to have a go at rewriting your code the way that I might write it - you say that you're a beginner in `foreach` so you should view this not as an "answer" but more of an "example".

A lot of this is just a matter of personal style.  I'm slightly showing how to avoid as many `\def`s (or equivalents) as possible.  I've managed to reduce it to the following that need to be calculated (I'm also using longer variable names that are more descriptive - since this is *my* version of your code):

- `\quotient`: the current floored division,
- `\intensite`: the `xcolor` colour mixing doesn't allow for expressions so this does have to be calculated,
- `\quasiNBdigit`: I find it best to avoid complicated expressions in the `\foreach` list.

It's also possible to reduce the number of coordinates that are defined.  Again, this is very much personal choice and will depend very much on what "readable code" looks like for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654957/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\newcommand \DivisionBase[2][2]{ 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    yscale=.7, % avoids needing the \cd macro
    >=Latex
  ]
  % I use \pgfmathtruncatemacro throughout to ensure that the result
  % of any calculation is truncated to an integer
  %
  % Work out how many iterations will be needed,
  % the -1 is as the loop starts at 0
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\quasiNBdigit{ceil(ln(#2)/ln(#1))-1}
  % Place the first node
  \node (a0) at (0,0) {\(#2\)};
  % The only thing that needs to be remembered is the current quotient,
  % We can also do the intensity calculation here
  \foreach[
    remember=\quotient as \quotient (initially #2),
    evaluate=\i as \intensite using 10*(\i+1)
  ] \i in {0,1,...,\quasiNBdigit}{
    % PGFMath uses Mod for truncated division
    \node[fill = red!\intensite] (r\i) at (\i,-\i-1) {\(
      \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\quotient,#1))}\pgfmathresult
      \)};
    
    % The 'floor' is redundant as we're using pgfmathtruncate macro
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\quotient {floor(\quotient/(#1))}

    % Calculations can be put in coordinate expressions
    \node (b\i) at (\i+1, -\i) {\(#1\)} ;
    \node (q\i) at (\i+1, -\i-1) {\(\quotient\)} ;
    
    % No need for the remembered coordinates here, just use the
    % calculated coordinates directly
    \draw[thick]
    ($ (\i, -\i)!.5!(b\i) $) -- ++(0,-1)
    ($ (\i, -\i)!.5!(q\i) $) -- ++(1,0)
    ;
  }
  \draw[->] (r\quasiNBdigit.south west) -- (r0.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\DivisionBase{57}

\end{document}
```

This produces the output as in the question, with an arrow below the remainders (as requested in the comments).

Comment: Could you add the possibility to draw an arrow from bottom right to top left, such as to read the binary writing of `57`?

Comment: @projetmbc Sure. Felt like it shouldn't go _through_ the remainders, so I put it below them.

Comment: Thanks. That will be useful for a lot of people.

Comment: @ Andrew : Wonderful ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `\global` before the loop isn't necessary.

The `\global` in the loop can be removed by using

```
remember=\myq as \mya (initially #2)
```

The

```
\def\cd{-0.7}
```

is not very elegant but since you do it inside the `tikzpicture` environment you won't overwrite a `\cd` macro that possibly exists outside of this environment.

We can move a lot of the `\pgfmathsetmacros` into the `\foreach` header (but that's not really any different).

---

I propose yet another approach: Using the previous placed nodes.

Nodes are indeed defined globally by TikZ and because of that you can reference a node (or coordinate) that was defined in a scope or inside the scoped `\foreach` body outside of that scope or in the next loop.

We place everything in relation to another node and a number of keys allow the fine-tuning of placement.

For every loop,

- we calculate

  - the remainder (`\dbRemainder`) and
  - the next number (`\dbNextNumber`) which
- we will *remember* as the next `\dbNumber`

and inside the body we will palce

- the node for `\dbNumber` at the south east corner of the last base node,
- the node for `\dbRemainder` at the south east corner of the previois node and
- the node for the base (which we'll use a value-key for) at the north east corner of the remainder node (we could also have used the south east corner of the number again).

If we reach `0` we'll place an additional node and break the loop.

For the first instance of the loop, there would be no node named `@base` from a previous run available which is why I place a coordinate `@base` to initialize the loop. (Similar to the `remember` key is this our initial node.)

---

For every node, these keys will be used:

- `/division base/every node`,
- `/division base/every number`/
  `/division base/every remainder`/
  `/division base/every base` and
- `/division base/number <step>`/
  `/division base/remainder <step>`/
  `/division base/base <step>`.

(The last `0` node only gets `every node` and `last number`.)

I've setup most of these styles aready so that they calculate the needed width from known values so that every column has the minimum width and the numbers are aligned properly.

For the color of the remainder nodes I've calculated a linear progression from `0` to `base - 1`.

---

The key `letter remaindars` installs a `every remainder` style that replaces a number between 10 (`A`) and 35 (`F`) with the corresponding letter using a LaTeX2e macro that is usually used with a LaTeX counter.

The key `connect remainders` installs a `last number` style that connects every remainders with the previous one.

Since PGFmath uses length registers internally you can't use any big numbers here unless you fall back to low-level counts or you use another package or library of TikZ that allows higher numbers.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\makeatletter % always a helpful key
\pgfkeys{/utils/if/.code n args=3{\pgfmathparse{#1}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt
  \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}}}
\makeatother
% like \tikzset but instead for /tikz we use /division base
\newcommand*{\divisionbaseset}{\pgfqkeys{/division base}}
\divisionbaseset{
  letter remainders/.style={
    every remainder/.append style={
      /utils/if={and(\dbRemainder>9,\dbRemainder<36}{
        node contents=\csname @Alph\endcsname{\the\numexpr\dbRemainder-9\relax}}}},
  connect remainders/.style={
    last number/.append style={
      append after command={
        foreach \j[evaluate={\nextj=int(\j-1);}] in {\dbStep,...,2} {
          (@remainder-\j.west) edge[-{Latex[round,bend]},shorten >=1pt,
            out=180,in=-90,#1] (@remainder-\nextj.south)}}}},
  % some defaults
  base/.initial=2,
  every node/.style={align=right},
  every number/.style={
    name=@number, alias=@number-\dbStep,
    at=(@base.south east), anchor=north east, node contents=\dbNumber},
  last number/.style={
    name=@number, alias=@lastnumber,
    at=(@base.south east), anchor=north east, node contents=0,
    text width=width("\dbvo{base}")},
  every base/.style={
    name=@base, alias=@base-\dbStep,
    at=(@remainder.north east), anchor=south west, node contents=\dbvo{base},
    text width={max(width("\dbNextNumber"),width("\dbvo{base}"))},
    append after command={
      edge[thick, to path={(\tikzlastnode.south east)
        -| (\tikzlastnode.west) -- (@remainder.south east)}]()}},
  every remainder/.style={
    name=@remainder, alias=@remainder-\dbStep,
    at=(@number.south east), anchor=north east, node contents=\dbRemainder,
    text width={max(width("\dbNumber"),width("\dbvo{base}"))},
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\dbColor{(\dbRemainder+1)/(\dbvo{base})*100},
    fill=red!\dbColor}}
\newcommand*{\DivisionBase}[2][]{% #1 = keys, #2 = number
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*\dbvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/division base/##1}}% local shortcut
\divisionbaseset{#1}           % let's apply our settings
\coordinate (@base);           % let's start somewhere for reference
\foreach \dbStep[
  evaluate={% we calculate the Remainder and also the next number
    \dbRemainder=int(mod(\dbNumber,\dbvo{base}));
    \dbNextNumber=int(\dbNumber/\dbvo{base});
  },        % the next number will be used in the next run as \dbNumber
  remember=\dbNextNumber as \dbNumber as (initially #2),
] in {1,...,#2} {% we could calculate the necessary loops
  \node[         % but I don't mind \breakforeach
    /division base/every node,
    /division base/every number,
    /division base/number \dbStep/.try];
  \node[
    /division base/every node,
    /division base/every remainder,
    /division base/remainder \dbStep/.try];
  \node[
    /division base/every node,
    /division base/every base,
    /division base/base \dbStep/.try];
  \ifnum\dbNextNumber=0
    \node[/division base/every node, /division base/last number];
    \breakforeach
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\DivisionBase{57}
\DivisionBase[base=135]{10000}
\DivisionBase[letter remainders, base=16]{4089}
\DivisionBase[connect remainders, last number/.append style=blue!50]{57}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Qrrbrbirlbel. It's very beautiful. But I can't see the letters. Here is an extract of my console :              (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
./DivisionStack-pgfkeys.tex:84: Extra \else.
\pgfkeys@parse ...uturelet \pgfkeys@possiblerelax 
                                                  \pgfkeys@parse@main 
l.84 ...sionBase[letter remainders, base=16]{4089}

Comment: @Clairon I can't reproduce this with the code from my answer. The letters are produced by `\csname @Alph\endcsname{…}`, if you don't need it, remove the `letter remainders` key. Maybe your TeXLive 2020 instance is too old? (2022 is current.)